# getting 401 error on safari (mac) and all browsers works fine

Tags: authentication, next.js, browser, safari

i have website in which i am using login authentication,my login authentication process works fine on all browsers except Safari(Mac). my api call gives me 401 error. I have checked in network tab , api request header conatins Authorization :token. i want my webite works on safari also. my application is based on next js and i have corrected api.because all browsers works fine.

I have tried some solution also like end url with / and setting secure:true and SameSite:"Strict" while setting cookies.but still problem persists

i dont have control and access to backend code.
front end code :-
const handleSubmit = async () => {
setLoading(true)
// event.preventDefault();

```
const data = {
  phone: userNumber,
  otpCode: finalOtp
};

try {
  // Make the POST request using Axios
  const response = await axios.post('https://myapi-domain/api/auth/otpVerify/', data);

  const expirationTime = 4; // in hours
  const now = new Date();
  now.setTime(now.getTime() + expirationTime * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  Cookies.set("jazz_token", response.data.access_token, { 
    expires: now ,
    secure: true ,
    SameSite:"Strict"
  });
  setLoading(false)
  handleOtpMessage('success',response.data.message)
  window.location.href= '/'
} catch (error) {
  // Handle any errors that occurred during the request
  const typedError = error as ErrorResponse;
  console.error('Error:', typedError.response.data.message);
  // Swal.fire(typedError.response.data.message);
  handleOtpMessage('error',typedError.response.data.message)
  setOtp1('')
  setOtp2('')
  setOtp3('')
  setOtp4('')
  setLoading(false);
}
```

};

Comment: Could you share your code please for both the login page and the backend service that handles authentication?

Comment: i have entered my front end code here.and i  dont have control and access to backend code.